# Is there a way to hide or disable an android bluetooth pairing request prompt?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have written some code that successfully pairs an android phone with a bluetooth headset without being prompted for pairing. I have tested it on these devices which all pair/bond without any U/I prompt

- Galaxy S6 Edge on Android 7
- Galaxy S7 on Android 8.0.0
- Galaxy S8 on Android 9

For the Galaxy S9 on Android 9 however, I do get a prompt

[image: prompt]

If I accept the prompt by clicking okay, everything works as expected. I have tried pairing/unpairing to see if a recognized device would not prompt again, but I am always prompted.

Does anyone know if there is a way, either programmatically via Java, or some setting on the phone, that will allow me to turn off this prompt for a headset?

The documentation for [android bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#java) did not really help, and I was unable to find any post that described how to disable this prompt.